# Modernizr error when using Chrome on Android devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, geolocation, modernizr

I am having an issue that I just noticed and have never seen with my previously released code.  In js I am calling

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()...
```

I also have coded the success and error portions of the call back.  The issue I am having is that on Android devices using Chrome, I am always receiving the error **"[object PositionError]"**

If I use Firefox on the same device it is fine.  All iOS devices I have tested also work.

Has anyone else run into this issue and if so, did you find a solution.

This is my full block of code:

```
  if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function (position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            callback(lat, lng);
        }
        , function (err) {
            // 1 = PERMISSION_DENIED
            // 2 = POSITION UNAVAILABLE
            // 3 = TIMEOUT
            //if (err.code == err.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            alert(err);
            alert('Current location could not be obtained from the device.\r\nCheck your GPS settings.');
            //}
        }
        , { timeout: 10000 }//10 secs.
    );
} else {
    alert('This device does not support GPS locations.');
}
```

Comment: Are you running this code on an http or https page?

Comment: It is http not https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As of Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en), you are no longer able to access geolocation APIs from non https web pages.

Thanks to projects like [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), you can now get an SSL certificate for free, however.

Comment: Thanks.
I will talk to my network admin to set this up.  I checked out the site, but didn't see a way to set it up for Windows IIS.
Thanks again, at least I know this can be fixed now.